# How to receive payment data or user data from PayPal using paypal_permissions gem or other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, rubygems, report, paypal

I'm using Rails and need to make reports about payments. I need to receive information about payments. I can't get how to do it.

I found paypal_permissions gem to get permissions to obtaion personal info. I need more, so I changed it. In function update added TRANSACTION_DETAILS, added get_transaction_details_data merchant.

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController

def update
 callback_url = URI.encode(merchants_request_permissions_callback_url)
permissions =  'EXPRESS_CHECKOUT,DIRECT_PAYMENT,ACCESS_BASIC_PERSONAL_DATA,ACCESS_ADVANCED_PERSONAL_DATA,TRANSACTION_DETAILS'

def get_transaction_details_data merchant
 access_token = merchant.ppp_access_token
 verifier = merchant.ppp_access_token_verifier
::PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS_GATEWAY.get_transaction_details_data(access_token, verifier)
 end
end
```

Is it correct ?
How I can receive transaction data and personal data ?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: @thomasfedb, I tried to get access to account - it worked.Requst goes to PayPal and asks permition. I don't know how request data(personal data). Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this gem : [paypal_adaptive](https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive) ?

Comment: I can pay using this gem, but how can I get reports ?